# Social media share buttons for each specific image in jquery gallery (Galleria)

Tags: jquery, image, share, galleria, caption

I'm creating a photography website using [Galleria](http://galleria.io). I want to add social media share buttons from [Sharethis](http://sharethis.com) to each image so that viewers can share a specific picture rather than a link to the gallery.

I'm using the Galleria History plugin to give a unique URL for each image, which works for posting a link manually, but when I've added share buttons on the main gallery page, the sharing links to URL on which the page was last refreshed. F ex. if I refresh/enter gallery at page.html#/3 and then navigate to page.html#/6 and try to share that image, the URL shared is still page.html#/3

I've tried adding the share buttons to the image captions, hoping that as the captions are linked to individual images, the share buttons would also link to the image they're associated with. Mostly the buttons won't display, although caption text does. Twice, share buttons did display, but when I refreshed the page to check they still appeared, they disappeared and wouldn't display again, despite me having made no changes to the code.

Should adding share buttons into captions in this way work, and if so where might I be going wrong? Is there a reason the code worked twice and hasn't since?

I have this ShareThis code in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "myID", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: true});</script>
```

and this is the code I'm using to try to add a Google+ button in the image caption (this worked twice and hasn't done since):

```
<a href="photos/03.jpg">
<img src="thumbs/03.jpg",data-description=
"<a href=<span class='st_googleplus'><displayText='Google +'></span></a>">
```

If there is a better solution to sharing individual images, that would also be welcome. The buttons don't need to appear in captions, this was just a solution I hoped would work.

I'm a photographer rather than programmer, and although I've done several websites for myself, there are huge gaps in my knowledge. Any help in relatively simple language would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a simple (*[minimal/representative](http://sscce.org/)*) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), to show us what you've got?

Comment: @David - here's the demo http://josephford.net/test/test01.html  The 1st 3 images should have share buttons below, respectively email, google+ and tweet.

Comment: And the reason I asked specifically for a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is because on JS Fiddle we can see the code. We can edit the code. And we don't have to dig through your site's resources and play with, or in, the dev console to make changes.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for replying so fast. I've now posted a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lartigue/qQdvV/5/